# Returning Option of (Int,Int) in scala from a List[Int,Int]

Tags: scala, scala-collections

I have a scala List of tuples, sorted in descending order by first element of the tuple.
I tried a few operations as below which can return me few elements from the list or `List()`

```
scala> val l = List((95,6),(10,2),(8,5))
l: List[(Int, Int)] = List((95,6), (10,2), (8,5))

scala> l.filterNot({case (x,y)=>x/5<2})
res6: List[(Int, Int)] = List((95,6), (10,2))

scala> l.filterNot({case (x,y)=>x/5<200})
res7: List[(Int, Int)] = List()
```

I want to write a utility method that can wrap and return Option type of the first element of the List which will be a tuple if `filterNot` has not emptied the list to List(). If `filterNot` gives me List(), I just want to return None. If `filterNot` gives me back a `List` with items, I want to do Option(l(0)). I can do it with regular if checks and all but I was wondering how do I do it the more functional way?

Comment: `Some(l(0))` or `None` is `l.headOption`, btw

Answer (score 4):

A better alternative would be to use [`List.find`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/List.html#find(p:A=%3EBoolean):Option[A]) which takes a predicate and returns the first match:

```
scala> l find { case (x, y) => x / 5 >= 2 }
res5: Option[(Int, Int)] = Some((95,6))

scala> l find { case (x, y) => x / 5 >= 200 }
res6: Option[(Int, Int)] = None
```

Note I reversed the less than to greater than because we're not negating the predicate.

Comment: You want >=, not >.